# How to convert a float to an Int by rounding to the nearest whole integer

Tags: type-conversion

Is there a way to convert a `float` to an `Int` by rounding to the nearest possible whole integer?

Comment: See also [a more recent `[c++]` Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620659/merit-of-inline-asm-rounding-via-putting-float-into-int-variable/37624488#37624488) for what actually compiles to fast code (`lrintf(x)` or `(int)nearbyintf(x)`)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually Paul Beckingham's answer isn't quite correct.  If you try a negative number like -1.51, you get -1 instead of -2.

The functions round(), roundf(), lround(), and lroundf() from math.h work for negative numbers too.

Comment: Rounding is one of those things you can get into arguments with others for hours.  There's also a school of thought that says the "add a half and drop the fractional part" biases the outputs upward (because `k + 0` doesn't change and `k + 0.5` always goes up for a given integer `k`), so they recommend rounding even halves down and odd halves up (i.e. `k + 0.5` rounds to `k` for `k` = ..., -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, ... and it rounds to `k + 1` for `k` = ..., -3, -1, 1, 3, ...).  Basically, the naive way can throw statistics off.

Comment: `round()` has non-standard rounding semantics:  halfway cases round away from zero.  [**The best choice is usually `nearbyint()` (or `nearbyintf`/`l`)**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nearbyint), because it can be done with a single machine instruction on x86 CPUs with SSE4.1.  (Or with SSE1 for converting to an `int` or `long` at the same time).  (`rint` is similar, but it's required to raise the FP "inexact" exception when the result isn't the same as the input.)  [Even with `-ffast-math`, `round()` doesn't inline.](https://godbolt.org/g/51eXsy)

Answer (score 57):

To round to the nearest use roundf(), to round up use ceilf(), to round down use floorf().  Hopefully this example demonstrates...

```
#import "math.h"

...

float numberToRound;
int result;

numberToRound = 4.51;

result = (int)roundf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"roundf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // roundf(4.510000) = 5

result = (int)ceilf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"ceilf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // ceilf(4.510000) = 5

result = (int)floorf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"floorf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // floorf(4.510000) = 4


numberToRound = 10.49;

result = (int)roundf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"roundf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // roundf(10.490000) = 10

result = (int)ceilf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"ceilf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // ceilf(10.490000) = 11

result = (int)floorf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"floorf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // floorf(10.490000) = 10


numberToRound = -2.49;

result = (int)roundf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"roundf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // roundf(-2.490000) = -2

result = (int)ceilf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"ceilf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // ceilf(-2.490000) = -2

result = (int)floorf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"floorf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // floorf(-2.490000) = -3

numberToRound = -3.51;

result = (int)roundf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"roundf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // roundf(-3.510000) = -4

result = (int)ceilf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"ceilf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // ceilf(-3.510000) = -3

result = (int)floorf(numberToRound);
NSLog(@"floorf(%f) = %d", numberToRound, result); // floorf(-3.510000) = -4
```

The documentation...

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/roundf.3.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/ceil.3.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/floor.3.html

Comment: `(int)nearbyintf(x)` compiles to better asm on x86, because it uses the current rounding mode instead of a fixed rounding mode (with a quirk that x86 doesn't support in hardware).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
float f = 1.51;
int i = (int) (f + 0.5);
```

Comment: it works. But, how? shouldnt the int be 2.01? then how does the int go down?

Comment: An integer is by definition a whole number, so how can it possibly have any fractional value?

Comment: well if thats true, then shouldn't
         
    i = f ;
just work?

Comment: Doesn't work for negative numbers, see ergosys for correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**round()** can round a float to nearest int, but it's output is still a float... so cast round()'s output to an integer:

```
float input = 3.456;
int result;

result = (int)round(input);
```

//result is: 3

[Working example for C++ here.](https://onlinegdb.com/ByAYoCeXI)

Answer (score -1):

```
(int)floor(f+0.5);
```

Try this...