# Float to integer conversion

Tags: ios, casting, nsinteger

I want to take the value from my slider and without rounding up, crop the decimals. So if I have a float value of 10.973. I want it in an integer as 10. I dont use negative values but if  the slider value is between 0 and 1 id rather it round up. How would i make a statement doing the following?

Comment: this is the default cast behaviour.

Comment: Even if it's the default behavior, it could be helpful to state it explicitly. People who are new to a certain programming environment don't know the assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
f = (int)floorf(x);
```

`floorf` however will round to the lower integer so `-2.79` will result in `-3`.

Comment: how would i round up on a positive number?

Comment: `ceilf`. So `2.12` will result in `3`. But again `-3.98` will result in `-3`

Comment: can you give me an example of how ceilf is used?

Comment: Simply replace `floorf` with `ceilf`: `f = (int)ceilf(x);`

Comment: I've found a post with the most common float-to-int operation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6107681/67579

Comment: f being my integer variable and x being my float variable?

Comment: Yes. The mathematical notation (`f` being the result of a function `f(x)`) perhaps `i = (int) ceilf(f)` was a better option :s)

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple integer cast would work.

```
int intVal = (int)floatVal;
```

Comment: how would i round up on a positive number

Answer (score 0):

A simple cast to integer should do:

```
int i = int(f)
```

If f is 10.973 i will be 10.  If f is -10.973, i will be -10.  A cast to int will simply truncate the decimal part.

Comment: How would i round up on a positive number?

Comment: You have the brackets around the wrong part. Should be `int i = (int)f`